# Как сделать autologin пользователя для lightdm?

Tags: linux, администрирование

Добрый нужно сделать чтобы ubuntu 16 пускал на раб.стол без ввода пароля. 
`[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=denis
autologin-user-timeout=delay`
В lightdm.conf не помогает.

Comment: К сожалению не вспомню подробностей, но мне для такой задачи тоже не удалось использовать lightdm и пришлось поставить slim, у него `default_user` + `auto_login  yes` заработали.

Comment: [первая ссылка в гугле](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#%D0%92%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) по «lightdm autologin».... ЗЫ: стоит проверить свои настройки pam'а, что они аналогичны описанным...